# Compare 2 lists that have same objects that might have changed

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class:

```
[Serializable]
public class MyObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

And I have extension method that returns if the object has changed:

```
public static bool IsChanged(this MyObject original, MyObject other)
{
    if (original == null || other == null)
        return false;

    if (original.Id != other.Id)
        return false;

    if (original.Name != other.Name ||
        original.Description != other.Description)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

I then get my list of objects and make a copy of the list, eg:

```
items = GetMyObjects();
copy = items.DeepCopy();
```

`DeepCopy` is an extension method that copies an object using `BinaryFormatter` so that the copy of the list does contain new instances instead of references.

I then change items (ie. their name and/or description) within the `items` list, and to check which items changed I do:

```
var changed = items.Where(x => copy.Any(x2 => x.IsChanged(x2)));
```

However, the count in `changed` is always the total number of items in the original list, no matter how, or if, any items changed.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just some debugging/testing ideas: What happens, if you deep-copy a single item and then immediately check the result like `var copy = original.DeepCopy(); Assert.IsFalse(original.IsChanged(copy));`? What happens if you test without deepcopy `var items = GetMyObjects(); Assert.AreEqual(0, items.Where(x => items.Any(x2 => x.IsChanged(x2))).Count());`?

Comment: You are probably mixing the concepts of object identity - `Id` in your case - with object equality - rest of the fields, which indicates to me you shouldn't be using lists for storing the snapshot but a dictionary whose keys are object IDs, also implying that IDs should be immutable otherwise you'll make an existing object disappear and a brand new one will appear somewhere. Your algorithm for comparing objects would build on those dictionaries then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically what you are doing is checking if there is ANY item in the copy that differes from the i-th item in the items list. So, if there is at least 1 item that has a different Name or Description, your counter of changed items will increase and the result will be the total number of items.

Comment: So you need to compare items that have the same Id

Comment: `if (original.Id != other.Id) return false;` looks a bit like your suggestion, doesn't it?

Comment: @grek40 Yes. Comparing Id was the problem.

Comment: @Ivan-MarkDebono that only explains things, if your IDs where not unique to begin with... otherwise, your check (which I quoted) *should* ensure that name and description are only compared for matching objects